# Как задать новые css стили в зависимости от url средствами php

Tags: php

Тема возможно уже поднималась, но ответа для своей задачи не нашел.
Есть страница (url) такого вида site.ru/node/*/edit
там где * значение будет меняться, но не зависимо от этого значения, если в конце присутствует /edit то нужно определенному элементу div поменять css стили.
Возможно ли такое на php выполнить?

Comment: такое сделать возможно. Но то что вы описали, выглядит очень дико и неправильно. Стили не должны зависеть от url страницы

Comment: Да, просто нужно сделать на скорую руку, а в дальнейшем уже все аккуратно поправить

Comment: @Виктор лучше не делать на скорую руку..потом правка этого и всего того, что это затрагивает - может выстрелить в самый драгоценный ресурс - время :) Если по самому простому (детскому) пути, то возьмите URL, разложите его каким-нибудь explode и проверяйте, если последний элемент массива существует и он равен edit, то меняйте класс в зависимости от предыдущего элемента массива. Либо через $_GET если в данном роутинге это настроено

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, так и сделал